# When I share a post on facebook the image is wrong

Tags: wordpress, facebook

All of a sudden yesterday...  When I share a post on facebook, it is using a different image.  The share box shows the correct image set as the featured image in the post but it uploads a different image.

Can anyone help...

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Do you have code that is attempting to perform this action? If so, post it. If not, this is the wrong place to be asking.

Comment: Are you using the opengraph meta tags in your markup?

Answer (score 0):

add a `meta` tag to your header

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $post->ID );?>" />
```